# Delete rows in pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables. Table `reports`

```
report_id | user_id | item_id
```

and `reports_messages`

```
report_id | user_id | item_id | messages
```

I want when I delete `report_id` on `reports` all related rows which matching `report_id` in `reports_messages` to be deleted too.

In my ReportMessages Model I have this relation

```
public function reports(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Report');
}

public function item(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id', 'id');
}
```

In Report model

```
public function reportedItem(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

So far I've tried this solution founded here on SO

```
public function destroy($report_id){

    Report::destroy($report_id);
    ReportMessages::find(1)->reports()->where('report_id',$report_id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('user.ports');
```

This deletes only in `reports`.. doesn't delete related report_id's in pivot table.
    }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel has the functions [`detach` and `attach`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) to deal with pivot tables.
So you can do this to remove the record in the pivot table:

```
ReportMessages::find(1)->reports()->detach($report_id);
```

This will however not remove the row in the reports table because it could still be linked to another object.

**Update:**
So, I just noticed, you don't have pivot tables, you only have two models that are linked.

You don't have to load the `reports()` relation in your query to remove the `ReportMessages`, you can just do it like this:

```
Report::destroy($report_id);
ReportMessages::where('report_id',$report_id)->delete();
```

This will remove the report, and all corresponding reportmessages.

Comment: Thanks. I've got this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()`

Comment: Oh, god. And I was trying to do it with pivot table. They are really only linked by models. Silly me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: thanks lot.
if relationship is okay it will works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm know I'm late but the best option with this kind of relationship, it is best to define foreign keys to particular linking tables in your table " reports_messages" like below

>
`$table->integer('report_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('report_id')->references('id')->on('reports')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('message_id')->references('id')->on('messages')->onDelete('cascade');`

When you do something like this, the pivot table data will be removed as long as either message or report is deleted from database without a need of detaching methods.
 Best option in case message or report has relationship with other data,such that when data is deleted message should be deleted automatically, in this case we do not have to worry about detaching data again

Answer (score 0):

To remove a many-to-many relationship record, use the `detach` method. The `detach` method will remove the appropriate record out of the intermediate table; however, both models will remain in the database:

```
ReportMessages::find(1)->reports()->detach($report_id);
```

official documentation is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)